# Is this the correct way to use VariantCopy()

Tags: c++, atl

I have used this method VariantCopy() to return the value of the variant  variable to the calling function but by the time it gets back, it is empty?
        I have these code

```
CComVariant varValue;
VariantInit(&varValue);
pCol->GetValue(&varValue); <---- it is empty after the call??
```

Where in the pCol->GetValue method is

```
HRESULT Column::GetValue(VARIANT *pVal)
{
    CComVariant varValue;
    VariantInit(&varValue);
    varValue = GetColumnValue(StringName);
    VariantCopy(pVal, &varValue);
    return S_OK;
}
```

//When debug inside this Column::GetValue(), I could see that the value of pVal is 2, the same as varValue after it is copied, BUT when it gets back to the calling function, it is empty again? What did I do wrong there?

Thanks

Should it be the same value after the VariantCopy() done?

Comment: check the return value of VariantCopy

Comment: can you provide the code for GetColumnValue?

Comment: The return value of VariantCopy() is S_OK

Comment: The GetColumnCopy() method is just to get the value of the column name stored in the database, and I could see the value return correctly.

Comment: What type is `pCol`? Is it a COM interface pointer? Can you show the MIDL definition of this interface? I suspect you may have incorrect MIDL annotations.